# nested for loop java poker game arraylist constructor

Tags: java, arraylist

this is my constructor so far for a deck of 45 cards with I'm writing a basic constructor that should make a deck of 45 cards where suit values are like (0-spades, 1-hearts, 2-clubs, 3-diamonds, 4-madeupname) and card values are (1-9 where 1 is an ace)

private ArrayList cards;

```
public Deck() {
    cards = new ArrayList <Card>();

    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,0); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    }
    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,1); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    }
    for (int valueKind = 1 ; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,2); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    } 
    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,3); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    } 
    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,4); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    }
```

what's wrong/missing?

Comment: *what's wrong/missing?*: that's what **you** should tell us, instead of making us guess what the problem is.

Comment: If you want 9 cards of each suit, it should be <=9.

Comment: Start by using a new `for` loop. `for (int i = 0; i <= 4 ;i++) {    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        cards.add(new Card(valueKind,i)); 
    } }`.

Comment: in the inner for loop wouldn't it be valueKind<=9? @ROMANIA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create value 1 - 9, then your for loop is in wrong condition. It should be `<= 9`

I made improvement to your code, so it is cleaner and fix the bug `<= 9`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by hendrawd on 11/13/16.
 */
public class Deck {
    List<Card> cards;

    public Deck() {
        cards = new ArrayList<>();
        makeCards(Card.SPADE);
        makeCards(Card.HEART);
        makeCards(Card.CLUB);
        makeCards(Card.DIAMOND);
        makeCards(Card.MADEUPNAME);
    }

    private void makeCards(int type) {
        for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind <= 9; valueKind++) {
            Card newCard = new Card(valueKind, type);
            cards.add(newCard);
        }
    }
}

class Card {
    static final int SPADE = 0;
    static final int HEART = 1;
    static final int CLUB = 2;
    static final int DIAMOND = 3;
    static final int MADEUPNAME = 4;

    private int value, type;

    Card(int value, int type) {
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you hear about the *int enum pattern* (I'd name *int enum hell*)? Avoid that. (Item 30, Effective Java)

Comment: @Andrew because enums add a lot more data in memory than using integer

Answer (score 0):

Since you dud not give me a clear question, I'll just give you some general suggestions about the code.

Firstly, your current for loop loops from 1 to 8, not 1 to 9. You should change the loop condition from `valueKind < 9` to `valueKind <= 9`.

Secondly, you can shorten your code by using a nested for loop:

```
for(int suit = 0 ; suit < 5 ; suit++) {
    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,suit); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    } 
}
```

Another thing is that I think your code will be more descriptive if you used constants:

```
public static final int SPADE = 0;
public static final int DIAMOND = 1;
public static final int HEART = 2;
public static final int CLUB = 3;
public static final int MADE_UP_NAME = 4;

//...

for(int suit = SPADE ; suit <= MADE_UP_NAME ; suit++) {
    for (int valueKind = 1; valueKind<9; valueKind++){ 
        Card newCard = new Card(valueKind,suit); 
        cards.add(newCard); 
    } 
}
```